# Laravel post request pass class with property with type of another class

Tags: php, angular, laravel, post, dto

I have controller in `Laravel`:

```
public function save(Request $request, ClientOrderDTO $clientOrderDTO){
        
}
```

Definition of above DTO looks like:

```
use App\DTO\ClientDTO;

class ClientOrderDTO
{
    public $id;
    public $userId;
    public ClientDTO $client;
}
```

And ClientDTO looks like:

```
class ClientDTO
{
    public $id;
}
```

And when I want to send post request from `Angular`:

```
save(orderDTO: OrderDTO) {
    return this.httpClient.post<RespDTO>(`${environment.apiUrl}/client-order/save`, orderDTO);
  }
```

I get error:

```
"message": "syntax error, unexpected 'ClientDTO' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)",
    "exception": "ParseError",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\crm-api\\app\\DTO\\ClientOrderDTO.php",
```

I can't have property in class with type as another class. What is quiet popular for example in C#.

Comment: It seems that there is a syntax error at `public ClientDTO $client;`. This is not `typescript`. In PHP you can define variable without specifying its type.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it works. But I saw that since PHP 7.4 it is possible declare type of property but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to migrate PHP from 7.3 to 7.4 version. From version `7.4 PHP` allow declare types of properties